# How to make vowel counting a function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Can you help me fix and correct my program so that I can enter a string, and the function counts the number of vowel letters and outputs the result.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].funcSecond
    (@a nvarchar(40))
RETURNS @returntable TABLE
(
    LENGTH int 
)
AS
BEGIN 
    INSERT @returntable
    VALUES (LEN(@a)) 
    RETURN 
END
```

Comment: Assuming you're speaking about English vowels, there are only five of those: a, e, i, o, u. Use `Replace` function to remove them from your string, and compare the length of original string to the length of replaced string.